# AngularJS + Safari: Force page to scroll to top when pages switch

Tags: angularjs, safari

I am having an odd, safari-only scrolling behavior using AngularJS.

Whenever the user flips between pages, the pages are being changed as if they are AJAX. I understand they are in AngualrJS, but the resulting behavior is that the browser does not scroll to top when the user switches pages.

I've tried to force the browser to scroll to top whenever a new controller is being used, but it does not seem to do anything.

I'm running the following JS at the top of every controller:

`document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

This is also a Safari-only bug, every other browser will scroll to top when the page changes. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or think of a better way to resolve it?

Comment: can you please post more code, such as the controller data, maybe the config setup of your routeProvider... etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using $anchorScroll()? it's documented [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll).

Comment: anchorScroll is for scrolling to the specefied element, if you just want to scroll to the top of the page I think $window.scrollTo(0, 0) should be used.

Comment: I found this answer while searching for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24549173/1578861 

Adding autoscroll="true" to my ngView element worked for me:

<div class="ng-view" autoscroll="true"></div>

Comment: There's another answer to this question that may be more appropriate for many: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21734337/199712

Answer (score 51):

`$window.scrollTo(0,0)` will scroll to the top of the page.

I just found a nice plugin (pure angularJS) that supports animations also:

https://github.com/durated/angular-scroll

Comment: I know it may be obvious for intermediate/advanced AngularJS devs, but remember to AngularJS beginners (like myself): don't forget to add ```$window``` reference on your controller, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: As an FYI, although it is clear in the README file, the mentioned repository has moved to [https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll](https://github.com/oblador/angular-scroll)

Answer (score 19):

you can use this:

```
.run(["$rootScope", "$window", '$location', function($rootScope, $window,  $location) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl){
        $window.scrollTo(0,0);    //scroll to top of page after each route change
}}])
```

or for tab switches you can use the $window.scrollTo(0,0); in your controller

Comment: I think this is the easiest way, only $routeChangeStart should be changed to $routeChangeSuccess, in that way the scroll effect will be invisible.

Comment: Like this solution. Thanks :) Add it to your XXX.config

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem while using AngularJS in a Cordova App. In a normal Browser or on Android i have no trouble but on ios i get the same behavior as discribed by Neil.

The AngularJS documentation on $anchorScroll is not that great so i thought to post this link which helped me way more:

http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use $anchorScroll

```
$scope.gotoTop = function (){
  // set the location.hash to the id of
  // the element you wish to scroll to.
  $location.hash('top');

  // call $anchorScroll()
  $anchorScroll();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Like [@nonstopbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1578861/nostopbutton) said, adding `autoscroll="true"` to my `ngView` element worked for me too. I mention this here because it was a comment to an answer and it was not easy to see his reply.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549173/1578861

Answer (score 0):

I'd a similar issue with Chrome. However, I don't know if any specific external library is causing this issue or otherwise.

However I wrote this piece of code at app level and it works.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
                $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call **$window.scrollTo(0,0);** after **locationChangeSuccess** event:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess",
function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
  $window.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you can actually drop the `$` from `window` and simply put`window.scrollTo(0,0);` without having to inject `$window` into the controller. It worked great for me.