# Can't figure out why page loads at bottom? Angular UI-Router autoscroll Issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this home page loads at the bottom.  Is this an angular ui-router, angular, javascript or CSS issue?  I've been stuck on this for two hours and not knowing why my html page loads at the bottom instead of the top is really killing my self-esteem as a programmer :/

Here is the home page:  [ URL Redacted ]

***UPDATE*** --
I solved this issue.  It was with Angular UI-Router.  See my answer below for the simple fix.

I use Angular and Angular UI-Router and the set up looks like this...

**default.jade**

```
  doctype html
  html(lang='en', xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', xmlns:fb='https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml', itemscope='itemscope', itemtype='http://schema.org/Product')
  include ../includes/head
  body(ng-controller="RootController")
  block content
  include ../includes/foot
```

**index.jade**

```
extends layouts/default

block content
  section.container
    div(ui-view="header")
    div(ui-view="content")
    div(ui-view="footer")
```

**Angular Config.js**

```
window.app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
// For any unmatched url, redirect to "/"
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        "header":    { templateUrl: "views/header/home.html"   },
        "content":   { templateUrl: "views/content/home.html"  },
        "footer":    { templateUrl: "views/footer/footer.html" }
      },
      resolve: { factory: setRoot }
    })
    .state('signin', {
      url: "/signin",
      views: {
        "header":    { templateUrl: "views/header/signin.html"   },
        "content":   { templateUrl: "views/content/signin.html"  },
        "footer":    { templateUrl: "views/footer/footer.html" }
      },
      resolve: { factory: setRoot }
    })
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Angular UI-Router recently updated it's app so that it automatically scrolls down to new views loaded by default.  This was causing my app's pages to load scrolled down.  To turn this off simply add the following attribute to your ui-view:

```
<div ui-view="header" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

Comment: I had the issue OP describes, and this worked for me, I did have to add this attribute on several of my child.siblings[n] ui-view div's.

Comment: Since this posting, ui-router has changed the default action of autoscroll. The `autoscroll="false"` setting now retains the scroll position when it loads a new view. However `autoscroll="true"` will load the top of the new view.

Comment: This solution perfectly worked for me. But when I use the browser back button to load the previous page it also scrolling to the top because of the autoscroll='true' . What is the solution for that?

Comment: Hi, for some reason this autoscroll is not working for me. I have a ui-view which loads a nested ui-view (3 views: header, content and footer). When I go to a state that reloads the content view and scroll half way, then reload my browser it will auto scroll back to that exact position. I have tried everything up to making a scrollTop directive using the $uiViewScroll(element). Nothing is working. It is kind of driving me insane right now. I just always want to start at the top of the screen but I can't seem to circumvent this autoscroll feature. Does anybody have a solution for me?

Comment: unbelievable. I can only say to myself: RTF. I wasn't using an expression in the autoscroll. I used `autoscroll="false"` instead of `autoscroll=" 'false' "`. Easy to overlook. Maybe something to catch in the code? Convert it to an expression if it is a boolean

Comment: For me, neither `autoscroll="true"` nor `autoscroll="false"` accomplishes what I need. What if I want the app to load at the very top of the window every time (not the top of a view), regardless of where they were scrolled in the previous view?

Answer (score 10):

here is a possible solution, i used a workoround, since auto scrolling wasnt working for me, so i forced my view to scroll to top. Hope this helps.

```
app.run(['$window', '$rootScope', '$location' ,'$cookieStore', '$state', 'CacheManager',  '$timeout', function($window, $rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $state,CacheManager, $timeout){


$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      clearInterval(interval);
  }
},200);

});



}]);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was also able to remove simply to the below which works fine and removed the 200ms delay...

`$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });`

Comment: A better solution is to use $anchorScroll() than window.scrollTo.  I am using anchor scroll now and it work. "$rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function(){
   $anchorScroll();
});"

Comment: "$rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function(){ $anchorScroll(); });" Doesn't work for me.
But this WORKS: $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){ window.scrollTo(0, 0); }); Simple and efficient :) Thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 8):

In your App routing module, Add the following to RouterModule

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

Comment: But why does this happen? It works without this attribute at times

Answer (score 7):

in the run block add:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  $anchorScroll();
 });
```

Of course you have to inject the $anchorScroll dependency

Comment: with ui-router it should be "stateChangeSuccess", as "routeChangeSuccess" is for ng-router I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a while ago. What is happening is you are on page 1, scrolled down the page I imagine, then click a button to go to page 2.  The router then doesn't readjust your scroll position when you go to the next page. I fixed this by scrolling to top on all route changes.

Comment: Adding example code showing what you did would improve the quality of this answer

Comment: I edited out because it doesn't add anything to the answer. If you didn't have time to write a full answer, perhaps you should've just made a comment instead?

Comment: I read and understood it purely as noise, much the same way that "hi", "thanks" and "hope that helps"

Comment: That is one solution Mindstormy.  Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: it might help to add code to your answer, because you're not actually giving any solution.