# Angular UI Router: Setting autoscroll on header view does not scroll to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, autoscroll

TL;DR: With Angular UI Router, is it possible to autoscroll to a view of the same state that the template displaying it belongs to?

**The Setup**

I have an Angular `1.4.1` app, using UI Router `0.2.15` and Angular Material `0.10.0`.

[Example Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Pc9IYA20PjAscojCXe0?p=preview)

There is a parent state called `website` and three child states: `home`, `foo` and `bar`.

The parent state has a `wrapper` view, which is displayed via the `<ui-view>` tag in `index.html`. It also has two other views, `header@website` and `footer@website`, which it displays via the `wrapper` view template.

Each of the three child states has a `main` view, which is displayed via the parent state's `wrapper` view template.

**What I Expect**

In the parent state's `wrapper` view template, when I set `autoscroll="true"` on the `ui-view` tag for the `header@website` view, I expect that the page will scroll to the top whenever the state changes. See the accepted answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711939/cant-figure-out-why-page-loads-at-bottom-angular-ui-router-autoscroll-issue).

**What Is Happening**

When any of the `ui-sref` links in the footer is clicked, the page does not scroll to the top.

**What I've Tried**

If I put `autoscroll="true"` on the `ui-view` tag for the main view, it works as expected. This is not what I want, however, because the header is hidden from view even when you navigate to a state from the address bar.

**What I Suspect**

I think the problem has to do with the fact that `header@website` is a view that belongs to the `website` state, and that `autoscroll` only works for views that normally are displayed on the current template. In other words, normally the `header` view would be displayed via `index.html`, not `wrapper.html`.

**The Question**

Is my suspicion above correct? Do I need to refactor, or is there a way to make this work as is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From memory, your assumption is correct. I've worked around this in the past via CSS top-padding on the main view's element

Comment: Thanks, Phil. I just tried refactoring the Plunk to test my theory, and it still doesn't work. See this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/TWdFCjRoUyUEOSteJzqQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't advocate DOM manipulation outside of a directive, a quick and dirty solution would be to add a scrollTo method in a `.run` block of your top level module definition, for ex:

```
.run(function ($window, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {

        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (document.readyState == "complete") {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1);

    });
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qPqy69o7F9aTjNbUTMGY?p=preview

(borrowed from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22166553/1516309)

I tried using the `$anchorScroll()` method of ui-router, but since your links are at the bottom of the page, thats where the page scrolls to, so you dont actually notice it doing anything.

Comment: Thanks jakeed1...I had seen that solution as well in my research, but wasn't crazy about using it because supposedly UI Router's autoscroll attribute already solves this problem. I'm just wondering if what I am seeing is a bug in autoscroll's use of the [$uiViewScroll](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$uiViewScroll) service, or if I'm just doing something wrong.