# angular-wizard scroll to top on click of next

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using this plugin https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard to create a multi step form in my ionic application . The problem is the page stays in the bottom when I move from one step to another . How can I make to page to scroll top when ever i switch between steps.

Comment: You can have a look at all the suggestions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055952/changing-route-doesnt-scroll-to-top-in-the-new-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `on-finish` directive you could use to trigger a scroll to top (use it like a `ng-click` - binding a function as directive value).

> **on-finish**: Here you can put a function to be called when the wizard is
>   finished. The syntax here is very similar to ng-click

Or bind the same functions on a step directive:
`wz-previous` / `wz-cancel` / `wz-finish` / `wz-reset`

**Small example on view**

```
// In this case, the scrollToTop() function will be called before going to the next step.
<input type="button" wz-next="scrollToTop()" value="Next" />
```

**Scroll to top in controller**

Inside that function binded through that `on-finish` directive, you can apply the scroll to top.

Just inject `$anchorScroll` as a dependency to the controllers constructor, and call `$anchorScroll()` whenever you want to scroll to top.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.I was able to find the solution and now the page is scrolling top when I move from one step to another. This is what I am doing.

<input type="button" wz-next="scrollToTop()" value="Next" /> 



and in my controller I have added like this 

$scope.scrollTop=function(){
   $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
 };

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the answer.I was able to find the solution and now the page is scrolling top when I move from one step to another. This is what I am doing.

`<input type="button" wz-next="scrollToTop()" value="Next" />`

and in my controller I have added like this

```
$scope.scrollTop=function(){ 
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop(); 
};
```